# Is there a keyboard shortcut to move cursor one word at a time in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, keyboard

I love **CMD-Ö** and **CMD-Ä** (in German keyboards). Navigating through tabs is intuitive and comfortable.

But navigating through a command already typed into the terminals a pain in the ... - especially when the command is long. Trying to modify a command - may be correcting a spelling or adding an option flag or something - takes ages, because I have to navigate by cursor and it jumps only several positions per second.

**On Linux machines you can hold some keys pressed to jump whole words and such. That is much faster. Is it possible to do that on a Terminal of Mac, too?**

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. I've edited your question to remove the second one; please ask it again as a separate question.

Comment: @Nathan: I think the question is too broad, and ought to be closed as such.

Comment: @Philip I think I've whipped it into shape. Do you think it's still a problem?

Comment: @Nathan: Much better.

Comment: @Nathan, thanks for your effort. I am trying to make the questions better in future. I'll ask the second one in a separate question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>ESC</kbd> and then <kbd>B</kbd> moves back one word
<kbd>ESC</kbd> and then <kbd>F</kbd> moves forward one word

You can change the terminal settings to more sane shortcuts like <kbd>ALT</kbd> +  B and such: here's a link on how to do that http://blog.macromates.com/2006/word-movement-in-terminal/